# MySQL - Distinct per user/distinct with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the DB tables looks as below

```
-------------------------
date emp_name activity
-------------------------
2015-01-01 A button1
2015-01-01 A button2 
2015-01-01 B button1
2015-01-01 C button2
2015-01-01 A button6
2015-01-02 A button6
2015-01-02 A button7
2015-01-02 B button1
2015-01-03 B button3
2015-01-04 B button3
-------------------------
```

I'd like to print emp_name along with all the distinct activity that associates with them.

**Expected Output**

```
-------------------------
emp_name activity
-------------------------
A   button1
A   button2
A   button6
A   button7
B   button1
B   button3
C   button2
-------------------------
```

I've tried the following queries so far, but it lists just the first entry for each emp_name

```
select emp_name, activity from table_name group by emp_name;

select * from (select emp_name, activity from table_name group by emp_name) t1 group by t1.emp_name;
```

Another query was using distinct, but, anyway couldn't use emp_name, distinct activity.

Could I pelase request help to get this query right.

Comment: What about emp_name C?

Comment: I've updated the question Jarlh. Thanks for spotting it

Comment: And now my answer makes sense. Undeleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select distinct emp_name, activity from table_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct emp_name, activity from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp_name, activity FROM table_name ORDER BY emp_name, activity;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct emp_name, Activity from <yourtable>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
Select emp_name, activity from table_name group by emp_name, activity order by emp_name
```

Comment: No need to do GROUP BY, since no aggregate functions are involved.